# Правильно ли построено предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

С 2012 года закон об энергосбережении предусматривает обязательную установку
приборов учета, в том числе и тепла, в каждую квартиру.

Answer (score 1):

> Правильно ли построено предложение?

**Неправильно.** В ряду однородных оказались и **приборы** учёта, и **тепло**...

Плюс к этому неправильно трактуется закон: ни о какой обязательности установки приборов учёта тепла в каждой квартире речи в нём, по-моему, не было.

============================================

Вот что было в этом законе:

> *5. До 1 июля 2012 года собственники жилых домов, за исключением указанных
> в части 6 настоящей статьи,
> собственники помещений в
> многоквартирных домах, введенных в
> эксплуатацию на день вступления в силу
> настоящего Федерального закона,
> обязаны обеспечить оснащение таких
> домов приборами учета используемых
> воды, тепловой энергии, электрической
> энергии, а также ввод установленных
> приборов учета в эксплуатацию. **При
> этом многоквартирные дома в указанный
> срок должны быть оснащены
> коллективными (общедомовыми) приборами
> учета используемых воды, тепловой
> энергии, электрической энергии, а
> также индивидуальными и общими (для
> коммунальной квартиры) приборами учета
> используемых воды, электрической
> энергии** (часть в редакции, введенной
> в действие с 26 июля 2011 года
> Федеральным законом от 11 июля 2011
> года N 197-ФЗ.*

=============================================

**Можете написать примерно так:**

*С 2012 года закон об энергосбережении предусматривает обязательную установку в каждой квартире приборов учета используемых воды и электрической энергии.*

**Или так:**

*С 2012 года закон об энергосбережении предусматривает обязательное оснащение многоквартирных домов  коллективными (общедомовыми) приборами учета используемых воды, тепловой энергии, электрической энергии, а квартир -- индивидуальными и общими (для коммунальной квартиры) приборами учета используемых воды и электрической энергии.*

Answer (score 0):

... в том числе [=в числе приборов учёта] и **приборов учёта** тепла...

Без такого дополнения "то число" указывает на свойства некоего универсального "прибора учёта", который учитывает разные показатели, в том числе и тепло. Но даже если бы речь шла о таком приборе, нельзя сослаться на "число" того, что перед этим не обозначено - тогда нужно было бы сразу после "приборов учёта" добавить напр. "показателей потребления" - тогда "в том числе и тепла" можно было бы отнести к уже упомянутым "показателям". Без такого предварительного упоминания вместо выражения "в том числе" можно употребить выражение "в частности".